# SharedResourceScope fails aquiring lock

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We use the SharedResourceScope Activity in our build process to make the deployment to the Symbol-Cache 'thread safe'.

Since friday auquiring the lock fails on every build

> "TF270014: SharedResourceScopeActivity 'Synchronize Access to Symbol Store' timed out waiting for a lock on the resource '\netapp01-cifs01\tfs-droplocation\SymbolCache'."

and we don't have a clue why. Restarting all servers involved did not help, disabling anti-virus software, firewalls etc. neither. The network share is available as well and we checked all acces-rights, to be sure.

The MSDN does not document how the lock is established and decompiling the code did not provide a solution either because the search ended at the `ISharedResourceExtension`interface (`BeginRequestSharedResourceLock`) because it has no implementation in the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll` which contains the Activity itself.

Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: Have you resolved?  Which version of TFS are you on?

Comment: Yes it's resolved. We did a bit of try/error and searching in the TFS DB see the answer I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could not find the implementation but as a hint for others having the same problem.

The TFS (using 2013 right now) holds its locks for shared resources in the database in a table called:

```
tbl_SharedResources
```

Clean up this table by `null`ing out the relevant columns and the lock is gone.

In TFS 2012 (any maybe other versions) the table is called: `tbl_SharedResource`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for us!  Here is a good link with an SP you can use:  http://www.garyhowlett.co.uk/2014/09/03/teambuild-blocked-on-publish-symbols-activity/

Comment: Great! We added a nagios warning too, so we get notified if a lock is not cleaned in time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the "MaxWaitTime" property of SharedResourceScope Activity "New TimeSpan(1,0,0)" to see whether it is helpful.

Comment: We already set a defined timeout. The problem is that we don't know why the lock fails since last week.